# Recursive method parsing through elements

Tags: java, dom, recursion

I have an xml which consists of elements xx and xxt. Each xxt contains one or more xx elements. Each xx has an "cap" and "act" attributes. What I need to do is put all the cap-act values stored in a map.

Now note that my xml can contain 0 or an indefinite number of xxt. Thus, this should be done recursively. For now, I just did the simple parse when there are no xxt elements :

```
  for (Element element: (List<Element>) minfo.elements()) {
        if (element.getName().equals("xx")) {
            String cap = element.attributeValue("cap").trim();
            String act = element.attributeValue("act").trim();
            map.put(cap,act);
        }
        else if(element.getName().equals(xxt)){
            //TODO recursive method 
        }
    }
```

An example of xml could be like this:

```
    <xx cap="Min" act="act1"/>
    <xx cap="Ver" act="asd" />
    <xx cap="Tan" act="fw" />
    <xxt id="PR" cap="A">
      <xx cap="tY" act="ate" />
      <xx cap="Tn" act="bga" />
      <xx cap="Tn" act="sga" />
      <xxt cap="an" act="y34" />
          <xx cap="Miu" act="sahg"/>
      </xxt>
    </xxt>
    <xx cap="Mzt" act="act1"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to create a method which takes in parameter the node to analyze and go through its children.

When a 'xx' is found, it is added to the map.
When a 'xxt' is found, you call the function by passing the 'xxt' node as parameter.

```
public function void analyze(Element element) {
    for (Element child : (List<Element>) element.elements()) {
        if (child.getName().equals("xx")) {
            String cap = child.attributeValue("cap").trim();
            String act = child.attributeValue("act").trim();
            map.put(cap,act);
        } else if(child.getName().equals("xxt")){
            analyze(child);
        }
    }
}

// To start recursivity
analyze(minfo);
```

This code won't compile but it is to give you an example.